# Integral extensions of the ring of multivariate polynomials

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element) over $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be the field generated by $\alpha$ and let  $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of elements of $K$ that are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.
A classical result says that:

**Claim 1:** There exists an integer $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq{1\over d}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ be the ring of polynomials with integral coefficients, let $\beta$ be integral over $A$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\beta)$ be the field generated by $A$ and $\beta$. Let $A'$ be the ring of elements of $B$ which are integral over $A$.  then we have:

**Claim 2:** There exists a polynomial $p\in A$ such that $A'\subseteq{1\over p}A[\beta]$.

This can be proved by a straightforward modification of [this](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~chanhh/notes/MA5202.pdf) proof of Claim 1, see Theorem 4.1.1.

**My question:** is there a reference to an explicit proof of Claim 2?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found a reference:

Paulo Ribenboim,
*Classical theory of algebraic numbers*,
Springer-Verlag, 2001, 681 pp.

**Section 6.1, Statement B:**
Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain, $F$ its field of quotients, let $K$
be a separable extension of degree $n$ of $F$, and let $A$ be the integral closure
of $R$ in $K$. Then there exist free $R$-modules $M$ and $M'$ of rank $n$, such that
$M'\subseteq A\subseteq M$. Explicitly, if $K = F(t)$ with $t \in A$, if $d$ is the discriminant of $t$ in $K|F$, then
$$M' = R\oplus Rt \oplus\ldots\oplus Rt^{n-1}= R[t],\;\;\;\;\;\;\; M = (1/d)R[t].
$$